# How to pass audio stream recorded with WebRTC to Google Speech api for realtime transcription?

Tags: webrtc, google-speech-api, matroska

What I'm trying to do is get real time transcription for video recorded in the browser with webRTC. Use case is basically subtitles in real time like google hangouts has.

So I have a WebRTC program running in the browser. It sends webm objects back to the server. They are linear32 audio encodings. Google speech to text only accepts linear16 or Flac files.

Is there a way to convert linear32 to linear16 in real time?

Otherwise has anyone been able to hook up webRTC with Google speech to get real time transcriptions working?

Any advice on where to look to solve this problem would be great

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I’m trying to do a similar thing using Azure text to speech and speech to speech

Answer (score 2):

Check out this repository it might help you - https://github.com/muaz-khan/Translator

Translator.js is a JavaScript library built top on Google Speech-Recognition & Translation API to transcript and translate voice and text. It supports many locales and brings globalization in WebRTC!

Comment: Thanks Karthik, but the code in that implementation is back from 2016 and doesn't seem to be set up for live transcription in real time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and failed with webRTC. I recommend you use the [Web Audio Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) instead if you are just interested in transcribing the audio from the video.

Here is how I did it with a nodejs sever and react client app. It is uploaded to [github here](https://github.com/untilhamza/Google-speech-to-text-App-in-react/tree/main)

1. You need an audio worklet script. (Put it in the public folder because that is where the API expects to find it)

**recorderWorkletProcessor.js** (saved in `public/src/worklets/recorderWorkletProcessor.js`)

```
/**
  An in-place replacement for ScriptProcessorNode using AudioWorklet
*/
class RecorderProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  // 0. Determine the buffer size (this is the same as the 1st argument of ScriptProcessor)
  bufferSize = 2048;
  // 1. Track the current buffer fill level
  _bytesWritten = 0;

  // 2. Create a buffer of fixed size
  _buffer = new Float32Array(this.bufferSize);

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initBuffer();
  }

  initBuffer() {
    this._bytesWritten = 0;
  }

  isBufferEmpty() {
    return this._bytesWritten === 0;
  }

  isBufferFull() {
    return this._bytesWritten === this.bufferSize;
  }

  /**
   * @param {Float32Array[][]} inputs
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  process(inputs) {
    // Grabbing the 1st channel similar to ScriptProcessorNode
    this.append(inputs[0][0]);

    return true;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {Float32Array} channelData
   */
  append(channelData) {
    if (this.isBufferFull()) {
      this.flush();
    }

    if (!channelData) return;

    for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length; i++) {
      this._buffer[this._bytesWritten++] = channelData[i];
    }
  }

  flush() {
    // trim the buffer if ended prematurely
    const buffer = this._bytesWritten < this.bufferSize ? this._buffer.slice(0, this._bytesWritten) : this._buffer;
    const result = this.downsampleBuffer(buffer, 44100, 16000);
    this.port.postMessage(result);
    this.initBuffer();
  }

  downsampleBuffer(buffer, sampleRate, outSampleRate) {
    if (outSampleRate == sampleRate) {
      return buffer;
    }
    if (outSampleRate > sampleRate) {
      throw new Error("downsampling rate show be smaller than original sample rate");
    }
    var sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / outSampleRate;
    var newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    var result = new Int16Array(newLength);
    var offsetResult = 0;
    var offsetBuffer = 0;
    while (offsetResult < result.length) {
      var nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
      var accum = 0,
        count = 0;
      for (var i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
        accum += buffer[i];
        count++;
      }

      result[offsetResult] = Math.min(1, accum / count) * 0x7fff;
      offsetResult++;
      offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
    }
    return result.buffer;
  }
}

registerProcessor("recorder.worklet", RecorderProcessor);
```

Install Socket.io-client on front end

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

**React component code**

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { default as React, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

const sampleRate = 16000;

const getMediaStream = () =>
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      deviceId: "default",
      sampleRate: sampleRate,
      sampleSize: 16,
      channelCount: 1,
    },
    video: false,
  });

interface WordRecognized {
  final: boolean;
  text: string;
}

const AudioToText: React.FC = () => {
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState<io.Socket>();
  const [currentRecognition, setCurrentRecognition] = useState<string>();
  const [recognitionHistory, setRecognitionHistory] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [recorder, setRecorder] = useState<any>();
  const processorRef = useRef<any>();
  const audioContextRef = useRef<any>();
  const audioInputRef = useRef<any>();

  const speechRecognized = (data: WordRecognized) => {
    if (data.final) {
      setCurrentRecognition("...");
      setRecognitionHistory((old) => [data.text, ...old]);
    } else setCurrentRecognition(data.text + "...");
  };

  const connect = () => {
    connection?.disconnect();
    const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8081");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected", socket.id);
      setConnection(socket);
    });

    socket.emit("send_message", "hello world");

    socket.emit("startGoogleCloudStream");

    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log("received message", data);
    });

    socket.on("receive_audio_text", (data) => {
      speechRecognized(data);
      console.log("received audio text", data);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("disconnected", socket.id);
    });
  };

  const disconnect = () => {
    if (!connection) return;
    connection?.emit("endGoogleCloudStream");
    connection?.disconnect();
    processorRef.current?.disconnect();
    audioInputRef.current?.disconnect();
    audioContextRef.current?.close();
    setConnection(undefined);
    setRecorder(undefined);
    setIsRecording(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (connection) {
        if (isRecording) {
          return;
        }

        const stream = await getMediaStream();

        audioContextRef.current = new window.AudioContext();

        await audioContextRef.current.audioWorklet.addModule(
          "/src/worklets/recorderWorkletProcessor.js"
        );

        audioContextRef.current.resume();

        audioInputRef.current =
          audioContextRef.current.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        processorRef.current = new AudioWorkletNode(
          audioContextRef.current,
          "recorder.worklet"
        );

        processorRef.current.connect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
        audioContextRef.current.resume();

        audioInputRef.current.connect(processorRef.current);

        processorRef.current.port.onmessage = (event: any) => {
          const audioData = event.data;
          connection.emit("send_audio_data", { audio: audioData });
        };
        setIsRecording(true);
      } else {
        console.error("No connection");
      }
    })();
    return () => {
      if (isRecording) {
        processorRef.current?.disconnect();
        audioInputRef.current?.disconnect();
        if (audioContextRef.current?.state !== "closed") {
          audioContextRef.current?.close();
        }
      }
    };
  }, [connection, isRecording, recorder]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container className="py-5 text-center">
        <Container fluid className="py-5 bg-primary text-light text-center ">
          <Container>
            <Button
              className={isRecording ? "btn-danger" : "btn-outline-light"}
              onClick={connect}
              disabled={isRecording}
            >
              Start
            </Button>
            <Button
              className="btn-outline-light"
              onClick={disconnect}
              disabled={!isRecording}
            >
              Stop
            </Button>
          </Container>
        </Container>
        <Container className="py-5 text-center">
          {recognitionHistory.map((tx, idx) => (
            <p key={idx}>{tx}</p>
          ))}
          <p>{currentRecognition}</p>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AudioToText;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");

//use logger
const logger = require("morgan");

//use body parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//use corrs
const cors = require("cors");

const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

//TODO: run in terminal first to setup credentials export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./speech-to-text-key.json"

const speechClient = new speech.SpeechClient();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  let recognizeStream = null;
  console.log("** a user connected - " + socket.id + " **\n");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("** user disconnected ** \n");
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (message) => {
    console.log("message: " + message);
    setTimeout(() => {
      io.emit("receive_message", "got this message" + message);
    }, 1000);
  });

  socket.on("startGoogleCloudStream", function (data) {
    startRecognitionStream(this, data);
  });

  socket.on("endGoogleCloudStream", function () {
    console.log("** ending google cloud stream **\n");
    stopRecognitionStream();
  });

  socket.on("send_audio_data", async (audioData) => {
    io.emit("receive_message", "Got audio data");
    if (recognizeStream !== null) {
      try {
        recognizeStream.write(audioData.audio);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error calling google api " + err);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("RecognizeStream is null");
    }
  });

  function startRecognitionStream(client) {
    console.log("* StartRecognitionStream\n");
    try {
      recognizeStream = speechClient
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on("error", console.error)
        .on("data", (data) => {
          const result = data.results[0];
          const isFinal = result.isFinal;

          const transcription = data.results
            .map((result) => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
            .join("\n");

          console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);

          client.emit("receive_audio_text", {
            text: transcription,
            final: isFinal,
          });
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error streaming google api " + err);
    }
  }

  function stopRecognitionStream() {
    if (recognizeStream) {
      console.log("* StopRecognitionStream \n");
      recognizeStream.end();
    }
    recognizeStream = null;
  }
});

server.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("WebSocket server listening on port 8081.");
});

// =========================== GOOGLE CLOUD SETTINGS ================================ //

// The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
// The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
// The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
const encoding = "LINEAR16";
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = "en-US"; //en-US
const alternativeLanguageCodes = ["en-US", "ko-KR"];

const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
    //alternativeLanguageCodes: alternativeLanguageCodes,
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    enableWordConfidence: true,
    enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
    diarizationSpeakerCount: 2,
    model: "video",
    //model: "command_and_search",
    useEnhanced: true,
    speechContexts: [
      {
        phrases: ["hello", "안녕하세요"],
      },
    ],
  },
  interimResults: true,
};
```